# What to do when I have a "position: fixed;" header & an image slider "position: relative;" just below the header?

Tags: html, css

I have made a header using the CSS property, `position: fixed;` & just below the header part I have included an image slider with a CSS property, `position: relative;`. My problem is that when scrolling down the page the images tend to interfere with the header part. Please tell me what to do?

```
.header{position: fixed; background-color: black;}

.sliderbox{position: relative; width: 1200px; animation-duration: 20s; animation-name: slideranimation;}

@keyframes slideranimation{0%{left: 0px;} 20%{left:0px;}.....}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `z-index` option to keep the header always on top, like this:

```
.header {
  z-index: 2; /* This value is sufficient if the other content does not have a z-index value. */
}
```